# React-Chartjs-2: How do I add gradients in the doughnut chart?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I want to create this:

[Aspiration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4bXZ.png)

So far, I have managed to create this:

[crap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bufp0.png)

I want to move the color label descriptions that are appearing above the chart to the left side.

Here's my code:

```
const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [20, 30, 50],
        backgroundColor: ["#EB6262", "#39BDE7", "#0B8878"],
        borderWidth: 8,
        borderColor: theme.palette.white,
        hoverBorderColor: theme.palette.white,
      },
    ],
    labels: ["Pending", "In Process", "Completed"],
  };
```

```
<Doughnut data={data} />
```

Comment: const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "bottom"
    },
  },
};

Comment: Please try to these options, ` <Doughnut data={data} options={options}/>

Comment: @DreamBold Hi, thanks for the response, would you have an idea on how to make labels circles like in the top picture instead of a line representing the color?

Comment: Did you try the above options?

Comment: @DreamBold Yes, have done the same, but edited the question before your comment